# Angular 6 reactive form password validation regex pattern and confirmation validation

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I am trying to build a registration form using Angular 6 reactive forms.

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$')]],
  confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$')]]
});
```

}

How can I make the validation so that will allow:

- numbers
- capitals
- lower letters
- any special character
- min 8 characters

This regex I am using works fine but I cannot use any other special characters for example I tried `Demoo123#` and didn't work. However `Demoo123@` worked fine. I assume there is a problem in my regex with the special characters section. Do I have to manually mention all allowed special characters? Or is there some kind of shortcut for that? I read somewhere that regex don't like hashtags `#`... is that true?

Another issue is how can I make a confirm validation so that the confirmPassword value must be same as password field value?

Comment: minLength(8) should be suficient. To control equalty: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Comment: You want a password validation algorithm in typescript. Did you try google or do you hope someone here does your work. I checked google and I found several examples in 10 seconds

Comment: @BertVerhees: I am looking for a regex not an algorithm in typescript

Comment: You don't need regex if you want to allow anything. The only thing you want is an algorithm

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for that didn't know that. Quite new to Angular 6...

Comment: @BertVerhees: After reading the link JBNizet posted, I can see that can be implemented with a custom validator...

Comment: Of course, he/she offers you an algorithm and he/she says that you don't need regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177250/discussion-between-bert-verhees-and-user2818430).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add to the password field the pattern attribute. `<input pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$" >`

That's quite wired. Why I need to specify it on the input when it is specified in the code? No idea but it works.

Answer (score 1):

**TypeScript Validation in formGroup**

```
password: ['', [
   Validators.required, 
   Validators.pattern("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$")
]],
```

> message: Password must contain more than 8 characters, 1 numeric, 1
> upper case letter, and 1 special character($@$!%*?&).

Answer (score 0):

Passing a RegEx as paramater works for me:

`Validators.pattern(new RegExp("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{9,}))")`

Or we can use the forward slash to both the ends of the pattern:

`/your_pattern_here/`

eg:

`Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{9,}))/)`